# Emojis in careers messaging result in ��

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs, emoji

Stack Exchange Careers clobbered my  into ��. This offends my basic human right of using emojis in professional communication with prospective employers. It also probably means that somewhere in the stack, Unicode wasn't handled correctly.

Fair disclosure: I'm using Chrome for Android so I cannot check if the mojibake happened on my side.

Comment: For those left wondering: U+1F605 Smiling Face with Open Mouth and Cold Sweat

Comment: I'm not really seeing the difference: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3hvcW.png

Comment: @mmyers eh, http://i.stack.imgur.com/p3gmu.png :)

Comment: I see the differences too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CQgkl.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I apologize for this bug.  We begin every spec and start every meeting with an update on emoji use in our messaging system.  We have tests for this.  We get alerted at night when it fails.  I have no idea how this slipped through the cracks.

Bug is confirmed though.  We're not sure what we want to do yet because sending emojis to employers never really occurred to us.  However, times are changing.  We'll follow up after our now mandatory "What do we want to do with emojis in messaging" meeting.

Comment: Beatings will be administered after lunch.

Comment: Good. Regular beatings I take it? And what happens to the remote users?

Comment: Some of us have treadmills. We just make them go faster.